# How to build startup/shutdown scripts for 2 or more servers that require to run in a specific order?

Tags: linux, unix, systemctl

I have set up an application running in 2 servers:

- Server 1 contains the main Administration module
- Server 2 contains additional modules that need to start up after the Admin module is up and running

and have created the systemd files to start up things automatically after a reboot.

So server 1 has something like:

**admin.service**

```
[Unit]
Description=Start Admin

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/home/usr/startup/startAdmin.sh
ExecStop=/home/usr/startup/stopAdmin.sh
RemainAfterExit=yes

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

and server 2 has something like:

**other.service**

```
[Unit]
Description=Start Others

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/home/usr/startup/startOther.sh
ExecStop=/home/usr/startup/stopOther.sh
RemainAfterExit=yes

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

What can be implemented to ensure other.service (in server 2) only kicks off if admin.service has started?

Answer (score 1):

In **other.service** you can add a *ExecStartPre* ( `man systemd.service` ).
The syntax is the same as `ExecStart`.

or **other.service** can have a dependency to a check service **check.service**

In both the command will be similar to :

```
while ( ! nc -w2 -z <ADMINIP> <ADMINPORT> >/dev/null 2>&1 ) ; do sleep 2 ; done
```